# I can't seem to get the leading zeros to display

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a digital time clock to display on a 55 inch flat screen. My leading zeros on time display are being left off and I can't seem to get the right combination.

```js
window.onload = setInterval(clock, 1000);

function clock() {
  var d = new Date();

  var date = d.getDate();

  var month = d.getMonth();
  var montharr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  month = montharr[month];

  var year = d.getFullYear();

  var day = d.getDay();
  var dayarr = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"];
  day = dayarr[day];

  var hour = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  var sec = d.getSeconds();

  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = day + " " + date + " " + month + " " + year;
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
    d.getHours() % 12 + " : " + d.getMinutes() + " : " + d.getSeconds();
}
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
<p id="time"></p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230343/how-can-i-display-time-with-leading-zeros

Comment: You can get your answer by looking at both the answers from the above questions

Answer (score 0):

Same answer different location in code. Thanks everyone

```
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=day+" "+date+" "+month+" "+year;
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
```

d.getHours() % 12+" : "+((d.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + d.getMinutes())+" : "+((d.getSeconds()<10?'0':'') + d.getSeconds

());
    }