# Add 0 before single digit number of time format

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we add 0 before single digit number of time format.
Like if I have a time "0:3:25" (hh:mm:ss) format to convert into "00:03:25"

Comment: You have to use a library like moment.js or use switch cases in javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding "0" if clock have one digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278272/adding-0-if-clock-have-one-digit) and or [How can I display time with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230343/how-can-i-display-time-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't overcomplicate this:

```js
const time = "0:3:25";

const paddedTime = time.split(':').map(e => `0${e}`.slice(-2)).join(':')

console.log(paddedTime)
```

**split** the string by semicolons (:), that yields an array (hours, minutes, seconds). **map** this array with a function that adds a **0** before every item in the array, and slice the last two digits (you get an array again). Then **join** the resulting array by semicolons (and you get a string).

Or you could use a **regex** instead of the split:

```js
const time = "0:3:25";

const paddedTime = time.match(/\d+/g).map(e => `0${e}`.slice(-2)).join(':')

console.log(paddedTime)
```

The last part is the same with **regex** (map, slice, join).

And you also could use the **padStart()** (JavaScript built-in function):

```js
const time = "0:3:25";

const paddedTime = time.split(':').map(e => e.padStart(2, 0)).join(':')

console.log(paddedTime)
```

**padStart()** on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below (Explanations included):

```js
const time = '0:3:25';
const correctedTime = parseTime(time);

console.log(correctedTime);

function parseTime(time){
  return time
    .split(':') // Split them into array as chunk of [hour, minute, second]
    .map(pad)   // Map them with `pad` function below
    .join(':'); // Join them back into 'hh:mm:ss'
}
  
function pad(n){
  return parseInt(n) < 10 // If number less than 10
    ? '0' + n             // Add '0' in front
    : n;                  // Else, return the original string.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add split the existing time string on the ":", then for each portion, add the  "0" then take the last two characters. Then simply join the portions back into a striung.

```js
let time = "0:3:25";

function updateTime(){
  let newTimePortions = [];
  let timePortions = time.split(":");
    timePortions.forEach(function(portion,index) {
      newTimePortions[index] = ("0" + portion).slice(-2)
    })
   return newTimePortions.join(':')
}

console.log(updateTime()); // gives 00:03:25
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
var dateinfo="0:3:25";
var newdate=dateinfo.split(":");
var hdate=newdate[0];
var mdate=newdate[1];
var sdate=newdate[2];

if(hdate.length == 1 ){
hdate="0"+hdate;
}

if(mdate.length == 1 ){
mdate="0"+mdate;
}

if(sdate.length == 1 ){
sdate="0"+sdate;
}

dateinfo=hdate+":"+mdate+":"+sdate;
```

This is work for me